# how to find spatial frequencies of line in a image in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, frequency

I'm interested to find the spatial frequencies corresponding to this line from the entire image as shown in this link  http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=a0fi9i&s=5

[EDIT: uploaded pic]
[image]
can anyone suggest ideas how to find these spatial frequencies?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to convert the white line into a 1D signal and then find the frequency spectrum of that signal?

Comment: Yes..Can you give me a hint to convert this line in the image to 1D signal.

Answer (score 4):

The naive answer here is to simply use a [2D FFT](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/fft2.html).  If this doesn't do what you were hoping for, you will need to clarify your question.

Comment: I think the  spatial frequency refers to the number of cycles per distance or pixels.In accordance with this link http://sharp.bu.edu/~slehar/fourier/fourier.html assuming the image  is   made up of different sinusoids images as explained in thelink.                                                            I want to find the spatial frequencies i.e., how the number of cycles per pixel or distance are varying along the line .

Comment: @user1016528: That doesn't make much sense.  Something like a line is the sum of a bunch of sinusoids at different frequencies and amplitudes; it's not just one frequency. I don't know what "how the number of cycles per pixel are varying along the line" would mean.  Unless you can give an example, it's going to be kind of hard to answer this question.

Comment: Thanks...And as the _line is the sum of bunch of sinusoids at different frequencies and amplitudes_.Is it possible to find the different  frequencies of corresponding sinusoids that makes the line? Can you please guide me for this ...